# How to create correct vector grid in meter

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, create

I want to create a vector grid, with squares of 100x100m but have some serious trouble in solving this apparently easy task. I already read all the posts, but didn't find a good solution. Here is what I tried:

1. Using the research > vector grid tool: I always fail to have the right X and Y Values, it is never 100m, even if I have "m" as my default length.I need 100m but it says always something around 59,... if i measure it with the measurement tool. and also the vertical length seems to be slightly bigger than the horizontal length.
2. Using processing tools: create grid - I have the same problem with length.
3. Using the MMQGIS create Grid tool: Same problem as 1 and 2.

how can I change the way i calculates distances? I think I have to look somewhere else, but dont know where.

FYI: Running system is Win 8, 64 bit, QGIS Version 2.4,

Comment: Is your CRS the same for both your layer and the Project?

Comment: You have to use a projected CRS for Layer and project. WGS84 or any other latlong system will not work with grid size in meters.

Answer (score 1):

Any rectilinear CRS (coordinate reference system) will do--if the units are in feet you can just convert to meters. When you use a geographic projection the units are in degrees, which is what is screwing you up. spatialreference.org is a good source for information on different CRS's... I'd pick one out for you but I don't know where your focus area is.